# I'm using PSPad and need a regular expression that will find 4 numbers in a six number set

Tags: regex

I have pages of data in the following format:

{1,2,3,4,5,6} {1,3,4,5,6,7} {1,2,4,5,6,7} {1,2,3,5,6,7}

For clarification, I'm going to call each instance of 6 comma separated numbers surrounded by {}, a "word".

So in the example above, {1,2,3,4,5,6} would be a word.

So what I'm trying to do is find each word that contains 4 numbers of my choosing. So for example, in the sample above, I would like to find all of the words that contain the numbers 1, 2, 6 and 7. The key point here is the AND. I know how to find 1, 2, 6 OR 7 -- I need **AND**. If possible, I would like to replace the whole word, but if it just finds the numbers, I can delete the remaining 2 numbers of the word with another regular expression.

Some more information about my data: The numbers range from 1-25. (So I need something that has the capability of finding 1, without necessarily including numbers 21 or 10-19 or 2, without including 12 or 20-25.) There is never a repeat of a number within a single word. The numbers within a word are always in order from lowest (1) to highest (25).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

You told you are using `PSPad` and want to do it in the editor. I don't think it is possible using a regular expression. I would use `awk` or a programming language of your choice.

---

Here comes an example using `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/\y1\y/&&$i~/\y2\y/&&$i~/\y6\y/&&$i~/\y7\y/)$i=""}1' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

The `for` loop iterates trough all fields of a line, the `if` condition checks if that fields matches all the required numbers. If it matches all the numbers the fields gets truncated. the following `1` is an `awk` idiom for printing all the fields separated by the output delimiter (which is the input delimiter by default).

About number matching, I'm using the escape sequence `\y` before and after the number:

```
$i~/\y1\y/
```

`\y` matches a *word boundary* which would in this case being either `{` a `,` or the closing `}` to make sure the pattern above would only match `1` but not match `11` for example.

**Output:**

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6} {1,3,4,5,6,7}
```

---

Btw, the above script can be far more readable and maintainable if you save it into a file:

*remove.awk*:

```
# Applies to every line of input
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        # Check whether the field matches all required numbers
        if( \
                $i~/\y1\y/ \
            &&  $i~/\y2\y/ \
            &&  $i~/\y6\y/ \
            &&  $i~/\y7\y/ \
        ) {
            # Truncate field
            $i=""
        }
    }   
    # Print the modified line
    print
}
```

You can call the script like this:

```
awk -f remove.awk input.txt
```

Comment: I tried copy and pasting what you put above and it says there is an error in my search expression. Does PSPad allow for "awk" commands? Is there anything in the above that I shouldn't be including, such as the actual words awk and/or file? Sorry, new to this and have never really heard of an awk command.

Comment: Oh, you should have tagged it `PSPad`.. No, `PSPad` does not allow to execute `awk` commands. `awk` is a powerful programming language for text processing. It is installed on every GNU/Linux system. Since you are using `PSPad` I assume you are working on Windows, is this correct? If yes, do you have access to a Linux machine? Probably it would be the simplest to use Linux, however `awk` is available for Windows too.